# CrossDomain calls in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-domain

A request is fulfilled in all browsers except IE. Practical answer to this problem is not found. (If you do not swear bad looking). What I need to change or add? I Used window.XDomainRequest, but it does not help.

My request:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function(xml) {
                    processXml(xml, config);
                },
                error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var errorMsg = "Request on url: " + url + " failed: " + textStatus + " error:" + errorThrown;
                    alert(errorMsg);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE doesn't fully support [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/). It won't support sending CORS request with withCredentials property. jQuery will support crossdomain request only if withCredentials property present in xhr object.

Execute below code in IE you will get 'false' (unsupported).

```
alert(jQuery.support.cors);
```

**Update 1:**

It seems [IE 10 supports](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors) it fully. Workaround, If your sharing resource between sub domain (foo.example.com --> blah.example.com), you can originate request in an iFrame and use [Javascript same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) to share the resource.

Comment: IE 7 has zero support for CORS. But, if you don't want to send user credentials / cookie. Try setting $.support.cors = true;. It will work in IE 8 and 9.